# Converting a Dictionary with Lists of Tuples into DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to converting a 2 key dictionary with lists of tuples as values into a pandas DataFrame.  The data I am working with looks like this:

```
dictionary={'Week':[(week1,week2),(week3,week4)],'Numbers':[(number1,number2),(number3,number4)]}
```

Is there anyway to convert this into a pandas DataFrame that looks like:

```
Week   Numbers
week1  number1
week2  number2
week3  number3
week4  number4
```

I have tried forcing the dictionary into a DataFrame using `pandas.DataFrame(dictionary)` but I end up with one row with two very wide columns.  Any guidance will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) function (from version 0.25.0+):

```
dictionary={'Week':[('week1','week2'),('week3','week4')],'Numbers':[('number1','number2'),('number3','number4')]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)
print(pd.concat([df.explode('Week')['Week'], df.explode('Numbers')['Numbers']], axis=1))
```

Prints:

```
    Week  Numbers
0  week1  number1
0  week2  number2
1  week3  number3
1  week4  number4
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to flatten the tuples for each keys and call the dataframe constructor:

```
import itertools
df = pd.DataFrame({k: [*itertools.chain.from_iterable(v)] for k,v in dictionary.items()})
```

---

```
    Week  Numbers
0  week1  number1
1  week2  number2
2  week3  number3
3  week4  number4
```

Comment: I keep getting reminded that `itertools.chain.from_iterable()` is so useful! Nice answer!

Comment: @bernie thank you . one of the [fastest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/953097/9840637) too  :)

Answer (score 3):

Using only list comprehension:

```
dictionary={'Week':[('week1','week2'),('week3','week4')],'Numbers':[('number1','number2'),('number3','number4')]}
pd.DataFrame({
    k: [t for tup in value for t in tup] for k, value in dictionary.items()
})
```

Or `ndarray.flatten`:

```
pd.DataFrame({
    k: np.array(value).flatten() for k, value in dictionary.items()
})
```